# dropdown-menu no delay on hover. "bootstrap4"

Tags: css

No matter what I try I cannot get the dropdown-menu to have a delay.
The rest of the main navigation menu has a nice delay.
I added the "jQuery .dropdown-menu .delay(400)"
And tried adding "transition-duration: 800ms" to every css item I can find
But still no delay on the dropdown-menu.
Anyone else experience this?
https://rshweb.pro

bootstrap.mini.css:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 10rem;
  margin: .0rem .0rem;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
}
```

Comment: It is only because you are displaying your drop down menu using display:block and display:none, you cannot apply transition property to display

Comment: what would you use instead of  "display: none"  ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be using opacity and z-index to show and hide your menu, for example, add the following to the .dropdown-menu class and remove display:none; property from it

```
opacity: 0;
z-index: -10;
```

then on hover, add following to the .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu

```
z-index: 10;
opacity: 1;
```

This is just quick fix, if you use bootstrap you shouldn't be needing this,  hope this helps you

Comment: Also I do not see a ".dropdown:hover". Should there be one?

Comment: I have tried the what i said on inspector, it seems to be working from here, you might have to look of there is something else that conflicts with this, and dropdown:hover should be there, though it is up to you, you can keep it if you want hover on drop down or if you don't need delete that part, but that's not the issue here

Comment: Yes there might be a conflict. I tried everything I can think of and find by searches online, no matter what I try still no delay on "hover" with the drop-down menu. Anyone else have and suggestions?

Comment: Well there is a "dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu" And your above fix worked!!!   But it did mess up my hamburg dropdown menu, all nav links are open

Comment: Good to know that it helped, if you have issue with hamburger menu i would suggest you to use this fix with media queries.